# Why do client websocket close codes not match the server code?

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, tyrus, socketrocket

I have a Spring Boot Tomcat server that is handling websocket connections from clients that are using:

1. SocketRocket
2. Tyrus

I find that the close code provided by the server is often not the close code read by the client.

For SocketRocket, I close the websocket at the server with code 1000, and the client often reads 1001.

For Tyrus, I close the websocket with code 1011, and the client reads either 1006 or 1011.

Descriptions of close codes from [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> 1000 indicates a normal closure, meaning that the purpose for
> which the connection was established has been fulfilled.

> 1001 indicates that an endpoint is "going away", such as a server
> going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.

> 1006 is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a
> Close control frame by an endpoint.  It is designated for use in
> applications expecting a status code to indicate that the
> connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or
> receiving a Close control frame.

> 1011 indicates that a server is terminating the connection because
> it encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
> fulfilling the request.

I have verified the outgoing close codes using Wireshark at the server.

Is the close code just unreliable as a means of passing information from the server to the client? Do I need to implement something at the application layer that passes this information before closing websockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess, but the WebSocket clients you listed may not implement the closing handshake correctly.

Why don't you try **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** to see what's happening? [onDisconnected](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocketListener.html#onDisconnected-com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket-com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFrame-com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFrame-boolean-) method of the library's listener interface ([WebSocketListener](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocketListener.html)) is defined as below.

```
void onDisconnected(
        WebSocket websocket,
        WebSocketFrame serverCloseFrame,
        WebSocketFrame clientCloseFrame,
        boolean closedByServer);
```

The second argument `serverCloseFrame` is the close frame which the server sent to the client, and the third argument `clientCloseFrame` is the close frame which the client sent to the server. In normal cases, as required by the specification, payloads of the two close frames are identical.